# Qual a forma mais segura de mostrar ID (chave primaria do BD) nas páginas web?

Tags: php, mysql, segurança, criptografia

Estou em desenvolvimento de uma aplicação web, do qual seria necessário em alguns casos disponibilizar no HTML (para que o JS possa interagir) ID de publicações de usuários, ID de comentários e outros...

Exemplo:

```
<div id="cmt_IDDOCOMENTARIO" class="comment-text">
   Comentário......
</div>
```

A questão é... tenho receios em disponibilizar informações do qual o usuário não deveria ter acesso, principalmente o ID de resultados obtidos no banco.

Como posso fazer para "criptografar" esse tipo de informação, para evitar possíveis ataques, invasões e etc.?

Eu estive estudando como o Facebook realiza isso, mas não encontro basicamente nada na Web a respeito.

Comment: Nas aplicaçoes com que eu trabalhei, o id é apenas e exclusivamente para controle tanto de relacionamento mas como controle de informações internas, por exemplo pra fazer um update no banco. Nunca ouve a necessidade de "mostrar" uma PK. Qual seria a sua necessidade?

Comment: Quando preciso usar o dado na view desta forma, eu geralmente associo a um elemento do html.
Por exemplo, na tr eu atribuo um ID na renderização, este Id eu consigo usar no JS.
Se precisar criar algum atributo adicional, também é possível, tal como data-pk=$id.

Comment: Sobre ser seguro ou não, eu sinceramente não vejo necessidade de ter este receio assim. Essas tratativas se solucionam com token de sessão, middleware de autenticação, etc.

Comment: Atualizei a publicação citando um exemplo.

Comment: Entendo, mas utilizar as data-tags do JS ainda assim não estaria disponibilizando a ID/PK para o código fonte?
Digo... Supondo que o ID no banco seja 123, no html não ficaria:.
<div id="cmt" class="comentario" data-id="123"> Texto </div>
Continuando a ser "explicita" ?

Comment: Sim, ficará assim. Explicita.
Eu não tenho tanta informação para te deixar seguro que isso não é uma má pratica, porém, vejo em diversos sistemas isso e uso assim, acredito que não há problemas fazer isso, desde que você esteja seguro quanto às tratativas no backend.
Pensando rápido, uma alternativa, seria uma referencia no HTML que, através de uma API  (token, lógica mágica, sei lá) devolva a PK para você utilizar.

Comment: Mas, eu sinceramente não compreendo o motivo de você querer a FK na view. 
Um exemplo sobre minhas utilizações:
No Model eu trato as FKs.
Desta forma, considere que tudo se resolve por meio dos métodos já definidos que abstraem as chamadas, tipo: Usuario, Comentários.
Usuarios possue comentários.
Comentários pertencem a Usuario.

Dessa forma, você não precisa passar a FK, apenas o ID do comentário, por exemplo. Pois acessando os comentários do usuário, você terá o comentário específico pelo ID.

Ou seja, faz isso no backend mesmo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não faz o menor sentido criptografar isso já que a informação sem criptografia estará disponível no cliente.

O Facebook não criptografa nada até porque os engenheiros que trabalham lá sabem que tem eficácia zero fazer isso.

Se não quer usar o ID da tabela use outra chave única, mas em essência dá na mesma.

Não adianta esconder o sol com a peneira. Se quer segurança valide tudo o que chega de fora e não deixe usuário fazer o que não pode. Se há risco de alguém pegar o ID e fazer o que não deve é um problema da aplicação, conserte este problema.

Se algum usuário tem que ter algum direito a fazer algo potencialmente problemático, autentique ele para saber quem é, dar o privilégio só para quem deve e crie um *log* para auditar se alguém fizer o que não deve. Quem não tem privilégio não pode fazer algo de errado.

Se tudo estiver seguro, o ID exposto não é problema algum, não importa se é chave primária ou não.

O único problema que pode acontecer é você um dia resolver mudar todo sequenciamento de IDs, algo que não deveria ser feito, mas se fizer e alguém tiver um ID no modelo antigo, aí pode ter alguma inconsistência, mas novamente, é um problema da aplicação.

Não existe uma forma de você associar um item exposto sem uma informação única que vincule ao banco de dados. E estou falando de algo matemático/físico, não é só que não tem uma tecnologia que aceite isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pelas explicações, vou revistar a questão das autenticações então!